# Validation in ASP .NET MVC 4 for Contact type using IValidatableObject

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Statement:**in the below view, i can choose any one of contact type( like: mobile or email or skype...)
if i choose mobile, i should enter only mobile number in below text box,
if i choose email, i should enter only email details in below text box,
**Problem:**
My problem is how can i validate contact detail text box?
if i have selected mobile, it should accept only numbers,
if have chosen email, it should accept only email id and if i try to add anything unnecessary details it should display proper validation message 
I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and i tried to use `IValidatableObject` but i couldn't figure out how to use for this particular problem

[image]

Comment: what @Neel posted as an answer is valid but if you want to use IValidatableObject, you simply do the same thing - run a Regex on the property in question and if it fails, do a yield return new ValidateObject("ErrorMessage here", new List<string>{ "Field1" });

Comment: @Ahmedilyas but i have only one field i can't add both validation to one property my model look like this :  public int contactTypeId { get;set;} public string TypeValue { get;set; } so i can't add both attribute(email and phone) validation to one property

Comment: Right, but you can still validate however you want when the validation gets invoked for objects that implement the IValidateObject interface.

Comment: but validation is depending on what i choose in the contact type drop down list, if i choose mobile how model will get to know the value of contacttype and how should i handle this..

Comment: this isn't validation logic. this is more business/domain logic. if you chose mobile, then you enter any data in contact detail, you still need to validate it in some way depending on the type you entered. you cannot really have a generic all in 1 attribute that validates every entry. you need to have some business logic to determine the type of contact type id selected and ITS validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

what about giving the validation like this? i am not sure its the correct answer or not ..

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email_id must not be empty")]
[RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Please Enter valid mail id")]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter  phone number")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$”, ErrorMessage = “Enter valid number”)]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Comment: My model look like this  public int contactTypeId { get;set;} public string TypeValue { get;set; } so i can't add both attribute(email and phone) validation to one